# Need help regarding magento

Tags: php, magento

An issue in a magento website. I am supposed to remove an analytics code which I am not able to find out.

Things I have tried :

```
1) Look up on system > configuration > Design (magento panel)
2) template > page > header.php
```

*This code is attached right after the body tag. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know your Magento setup, a quick solution:

1) If the code is placed in a file, if you have shell access:

```
   grep -R "var _gaq" .
```

2) If the code is setup in admin, do an export of the database, open the file and search for the same string: "var _gaq"

When you finally narrowed it, you may be able to remove it.

Comment: This assumes the OP is using Google Analytics. While it is the most popular, I don't think we can make the assumption that that is what the OP is using without further information.